# which programming language is this? it's a file with *.bb extension

Tags: game-engine

it was in a file with a *.bb extension, so what's the programming language?
this is a source code for a game called SCP-087-B, there is two file for the source code but i put the content of one in order to determine the programming language it used.
this is the source: [SCP-087-B](http://www.scpcbgame.com/scp-087-b.html)

```
Global ark_blur_image, ark_blur_texture, ark_sw, ark_sh

Function CreateBlurImage()
    ;Create blur camera
    Local cam = CreateCamera()
    CameraClsMode cam, 0, 0
    CameraRange cam, 0.1, 1.5
    MoveEntity cam, 0, 0, 10000

    ark_sw = GraphicsWidth()
    ark_sh = GraphicsHeight()


    ;Create sprite
    Local spr = CreateMesh(cam)
    Local sf = CreateSurface(spr)
    AddVertex sf, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0
    AddVertex sf, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
    AddVertex sf, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1
    AddVertex sf, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1
    AddTriangle sf, 0, 1, 2
    AddTriangle sf, 3, 2, 1
    EntityFX spr, 17
    ScaleEntity spr, 2048.0 / Float(ark_sw), 2048.0 / Float(ark_sw), 1
    PositionEntity spr, 0, 0, 1.0001
    EntityOrder spr, -100000
    EntityBlend spr, 1
    ark_blur_image = spr

    ;Create blur texture
    ark_blur_texture = CreateTexture(2048, 2048, 256)
    EntityTexture spr, ark_blur_texture
End Function

Function UpdateBlur(power#)
    EntityAlpha ark_blur_image, power#
    CopyRect  ark_sw / 2 - 1024, ark_sh / 2 - 1024, 2048, 2048, 0, 0, BackBuffer(), TextureBuffer(ark_blur_texture) 

End Function
;~IDEal Editor Parameters:
;~C#Blitz3D
```

so what's the programming language of this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be [Blitz Basic](http://www.blitzbasic.com/b3ddocs/docs.php) judging from the overall layout and function names.